# Visual Studio 2015 does not find external .dll even after copying in bin folder, but only after copying to c:\Windows\

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, dll, vs-web-application-project

I try to build a Web-project in Visual Studio 2015 which references a c# .dll-project "dotnetWrapper" which is a c# wrapper for a c++ project "managedDllWrapper" which includes some 3rd-party 64-bit native c++ .dll.

The referenced projects and the Web-project run on .Net Framework 4.6.1 and x64. VS2015 uses iis express 64 bit.

Everything compiles fine.

When I start the local webserver in VS2015 (hit the green start button), I get the error message that that the "managedDllWrapper.dll" or one of its dependencies could not be found:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'managedDllWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'managedDllWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'managedDllWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
>     System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +25
>
> System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
>    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'managedDllWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
>
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
>
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +259
>
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +163
>
> System.Web.Compilation.<>c.b__143_0(AssemblyInfo ai) +29
>
> System.Linq.d__16'2.MoveNext() +293
>
> System.Linq.d__66'1.MoveNext() +100
>
> System.Linq.d__63'1.MoveNext() +73
>
> System.Web.UI.Util.GetTypeFromAssemblies(IEnumerable assemblies, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase) +217
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +266
>
> System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetTypeWithAssert(String type) +48
>
> System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type) +17
>
> System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +25
>
> System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +104
>
> System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +262
>
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET  Version:4.6.1055.0

Note that the native dlls (the dependencies) are in the web-project bin folder (copied manually).

When I copy the native dlls into my C:\Windows\ folder, the web application works smoothly and fine. Somehow, the web-application's dll search path points only to the C:\Windows\ folder, but it should also look into the webapp execution (bin) folder, right?

When I don't do a web-application, but a C# console test-application, which also includes the wrapper with all dlls, the copying of the dlls into the test-app bin folder works fine and the application runs. Only the web-application has this problem, not to accept the dlls in its bin folder.

Also, when I copy the dlls into the C:\Windows\ directory, and run the web-application, and then try to delete the dlls again, it says they cannot be deleted because

> because the file is open in IIS Express Worker Process.

So, maybe it is a problem of the IIS and not of VS2015, but I cannot configure my IIS (or I don't know how). I use the IIS express which comes with Visual Studio 2015.

All my research in Google and stackoverflow resulted in:

- copy dlls to bin folder (tried, but does not work as described above, only works for a C# console app, but not for a web-app).
- reference dlls directly in the project (not possible:)

  > "[..].dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."
- check if everything is 64-bit, and same .Net version (checked, 64 bit, .Net 4.6.1. Also: it works fine for a console app, but not web-app).
- change the web.config to add further .dll folders. But this did not help either.

I would be happy if the .dll could be found by my web-project in a different folder than C:\Windows\ , since I doubt I will be allowed to add 17 .dll to the C:\Windows\ folder on MS azurewebsites when I want to publish the site. Then, the path should be somehow within the application folders.

Comment: Putting it in the Global Assembly Cache (`gacutil /i`) is probably better than C:\Windows but I don't remember the arguments for and against that. It must be possible to solve the IIS case thouigh.

Comment: You've actually added this as a reference in your C# project? If so, in the `Properties` of the reference, try setting `Copy Local` to true and see if it references it correctly then.

Comment: You should look into using fuslogvw.exe.  You start a Visual Studio command prompt as administrative user, then run fuslogvw.exe.  You configure the tool to generate log files, and then attempt the load again.  Fuslogvw.exe will now generate a log file explaining why it was unable to load the assembly.  I've found this tool very helpful for these issues.

Comment: Thanks to your comments!
@user1438893, I tried to add the dll as reference, but this is not possible since they are not a COM assembly.

Comment: @BertCushman, thanks, I had a look at fuslogvw, but it did not give me meaningful logs. It did not log any error, but the web-page still claims that the reference.dll or its dependencies are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the problem one to one, but I circumvented the problem successfully:

By rewriting the c#/c++ wrapper with explicit dllimport, I adressed the dll files directly with path. Then, the dependent dll just have to be in the same folder as the referenced dll. This works also in web apps.